# How to update textiew text based on another variable in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I have the following code, shown below where every time I make changes to a text field, a function gets called, in my case doSomething(). However, I assumed that since I bound the value of the text to a variable, if that variable were to get updated, the textfield text would also update. This is not happening, and my question is, what would be the simplest way to make the textfield update its text every time the corresponding variable changes.

Edit: Just to clarify, I have no problem getting the doSomething() function to update other parts of the code, I am looking for the inverse where an external variable changes the text of the textfield

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DynamicTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  const DynamicTextField(
      {
      required this.value,
      Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  final double value;
  
  @override
  State<DynamicTextField> createState() =>
      _DynamicTextFieldState(value);
}

class _DynamicTextFieldState extends State<DynamicTextField> {
  _DynamicTextFieldState(this.value);

  final double value;
  late TextEditingController textChanged;

  @override
  void initState() {
    textChanged = TextEditingController(text: value.toString());
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: textChanged,
      onChanged: (text) {
        doSomething();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change the `TextField` value with the `textChanged` controller you set to that widget.

```
String stringVariable = "some value";
textChanged.text = stringVariable;
```

you can then update the state with a normal `SetState(() {})`, and it should update the value in `TextField`

Comment: I am looking for the reverse, I want the text to update in the TextField when "value" changes

Comment: oh sorry, I well update the answer

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately the text does not update when doing that for me at least

Answer (score 0):

Your *value* is declared as **final**. Meaning it can only be set once. Try removing the final declaration.

I also see you’re also declaring the *value* variable twice, instead of referencing the original value variable.

The second declaration should be in the widgets build method & should = **widget.value**.

Comment: I did try both those things, good practice regardless, but it did not fix my issue unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

this will update the text everytime `DynamicTextField`  get rebuild.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    textChanged = TextEditingController(text: widget.value.toString());
    super.initState();
  }
```

Depends how you use the `DynamicTextField` in another class. The life-cycle of `StatefullWidget` is call the initState once the widget initialize.